# Changing Paragraph Text to Stylized Span

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change paragraph text in a for each loop. This seems like a simple issue (specific to JS?). I'm new to this language, coming from Matlab and Java. Fiddle attached. Any help is appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/npkx3of4/1/

```
function myFunction() {
    var ps = document.getElementsByClassName('.test');
    for (var p of ps) {
        p = p.replace('a', '<span style="color:blue;">b</span>');
    }
    alert("Working?");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Right you are! Thanks. The script is still broken but that's one step farther. Maybe I need to access #innerHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `getElementsByClassName('.test')` should be `getElementsByClassName('test')`.
2. You should be assigning the result of replacing the `innerHTML` of the paragraph back to the `innerHTML` of the paragraph.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ps = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  for (var p of ps) {
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace('a', '<span style="color:blue;">b</span>');
  }
  alert("Working?");
  return null;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<hr>
<p class="test">a</p>
<button type="button" onclick='myFunction();'>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I should've realized innerHTML needs to be specified on both sides

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any need to add a period before the class name when using `getElementsByClassName`.

```js
var ps = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
```

Select only the plain text content inside the element, then replace all the specified characters before rewriting the inner HTML.

```js
...  
    for (var p of ps) {
        p.innerHTML = p.textContent.replaceAll('a', '<span style="color:blue;">b</span>');
    }
...
```